# How do I use size classes in conjunction with views in Storyboards in iOS 8? My views aren't showing up

Tags: iphone, ipad, interface-builder, uistoryboard, ios8

Perhaps I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how size classes in iOS 8 work, but as I understood it from watching session videos they allow you to define different configurations for views depending on two broad sizes that represent two device types (a small one and a large one), thus allowing you to use one Storyboard for iPad and iPhone and landscape and portrait, but just select the right size class for configuration.

Say I want to create my interface for an iPad in portrait orientation. In Storyboard it's a 3x3 size class grid, and I'm inclined to select 2x3, a compact width and a large height, which makes sense for the iPad, no?

When I inspect a view, at the bottom I have two checkboxes, a simple "Installed" one with no extra text, and one with "w Any h R Installed" beneath it. When I have only the bottom one checked (seemingly default behavior) and run it, no views show up. If I check the top one with simply "Installed" as well, it does show up.

So what's going on? Am I using the wrong size class? Am I selecting the right size class in the inspector? Do I have to individually select something for each view?

Comment: Did you solve it? I too have same problem. Can you help me how to get it exactly?

Comment: Installed = works for Any/Any. Any of the other Installed means it'll only work for that size class.